# Api key request in Python/Javascript

Tags: javascript, python, python-requests, api-key

I'm trying to make a request to an API. I've got the API key and read the documentation.

Documentation: https://info.nobil.no/images/downloads/API-NOBIL-Documentation_v3_20180808.pdf

The examples in the documentation seems to me to be in javascript.

```js
 jQuery.ajax({
 type: 'POST',
 url: 'https://nobil.no/api/server/search.php',
data: { 'apikey': nobilApiKey, 'apiversion': '3',
'action': "search",
 'type': 'rectangle',
 'northeast': '(59.943921193288915, 10.826683044433594)',
 'southwest': '(59.883683240905256, 10.650901794433594)',
'existingids': '189,195,199,89,48'},
 dataType: 'json'
});
```

Questions:
1.) Can I make a request to the server with python?
2.) How do I incorperate the api key into the code?

Would really appreciate a code snippet showing how!

Comment: _"1.) Can I make a request to the server with python?"_ I don't know if you can, but it's possible to do it with python. _"2.) How do I incorperate the api key into the code?"_ You have to send the API key in the request body in JSON format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you would use the `requests` library

it would look something like this:

```
import requests
url = 'https://nobil.no/api/server/search.php?mode=ajax'
post_data = { 'apikey': nobilApiKey, 'apiversion': '3',
'action': "search",
 'type': 'rectangle',
 'northeast': '(59.943921193288915, 10.826683044433594)',
 'southwest': '(59.883683240905256, 10.650901794433594)',
'existingids': '189,195,199,89,48'}
r = requests.post(url, data=post_data)
# do something with r
```

Read the docs here: https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/